# ASP.Net attributes["class"] = "";

Tags: asp.net, ajax, regex, attributes

I have a contact form in my web site. When I control the `mailTo` like this:

```
if (!reg.IsMatch(mailTo.Value))
```

I will add attributes: `name = class`, `value = error`. 
It runs correctly but when I tried to set `mailTo.Attributes["class"] = "";` it doesnt work correctly.

Codebehind code:

```
Regex reg = new Regex(@"^([0-9a-zA-Z]([-.\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z])*@([0-9a-zA-Z][-\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z]\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,9})$");
//Kontroller
if (!reg.IsMatch(mailTo.Value))
      mailTo.Attributes.Add("class", "error");
else
      mailTo.Attributes["class"] = "";
```

Web page code:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Always">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <span style="color: #777; text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px white;">İsim:</span>
         <input id="isim" runat="server" style="color: rgb(85, 85, 85);" type="text" name="name" />
        <span style="color: #777; text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px white;">Email:</span>
         <input id="mailTo" runat="server" style="color: rgb(85, 85, 85);" type="text" name="email" />
        <span style="color: #777; text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px white;">Mesaj:</span>
         <textarea id="mesaj" runat="server" style="color: rgb(85, 85, 85);" name="message"
                                            rows="3" cols="4"></textarea>
          <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" CssClass="sendbutton sendmail" OnClick="Button1_Click"
                                            Text="Yolla" OnClientClick="easyNotification();" />
   </ContentTemplate>
   <Triggers>
      <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Button1" EventName="Click" />
   </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: You should check the attribute is set first, and then, rather than set the attribute to String.Empty, simply remove it. mailTo.Attributes.Remove("class") should do it for removal. Note you could also add a regex validation control - one of the predefined validation expressions is for an Internet emaii

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if the attribute exists first. If it does, then remove it. Try the following:

```
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(mailTo.Attributes["class"]) )
    {
        if (!reg.IsMatch(mailTo.Value))
        {
            mailTo.Attributes.Add("class", "error");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (!reg.IsMatch(mailTo.Value))
        {
            mailTo.Attributes.Add("class", "error");
        }
        else
        {
            mailTo.Attributes.Remove("class");
        }
    }
```

There's no need to remove the attribute if it doesn't already exist and you aren't in error.

Personally, I'd think about using an asp:TextBox and a Regular Expression Validator: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.regularexpressionvalidator.aspx

You can just set control to validate, and an expression (of which Internet Email is a predefined selection available), and, in your server code, call if(Page.IsValid) { ... do stuff ... }

Also, Visual Studio.Net suggests this as an expression for an internet email address:

```
Regex emailValidator = new Regex("\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*");
```

Comment: My templete is cant support regularexpression and it doesnt works :(

Comment: If you describe exactly what is happening I'll try and help some more.

Comment: I've updated the answer with an alternative regular expression for you to try, too.